# How can I remove moisture and odor from wall insulation?

Tags: insulation, pet-proofing

## Backstory

There is a gap between the ground and the wall. Inside I can see the insulation that is there.

## Problem

Unfortunately the pet made this insulation a temporary toilet so it has been peed upon a couple of times.

## Trying to fix

I've removed the visible part of that insulation (by pulling it off as best as I can) and now there is this gap left, where the insulation is underneath.

I've sprayed the area couple of times with enzyme cleaners (including the gap with the insulation), it still smells weird inside. Can't really tell if its pee or insuline smell, if that's something.

## Request for proper solution

How can I make sure that the smell is gone?

Should I fill the gap between the wall and the ground with some kind of filler?

Thank you

Comment: It's really difficult to visualize what you're talking about.  Please add a photo to your question.

Comment: Yeah, [edit] in a couple of good, clear, focused pictures of the overall scene (hit the "sun and mountain" button above the text entry box) and a detailed shot or two of the problem area will make it _much_ easier for people to help you. I'm not even sure if this is indoor "ground" or outdoor "ground"...

Comment: If it's from a dog, keep spraying with bleach. If it's from a cat, forget it.

Answer (score 1):

You’ll need to expose area, clean with bleach and let air out for a day before installing new insulation then  covering area.
Kind of hard to visualize w/ out photo.